# Open current page URL in new window when click on chrome extension icon

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I have created chrome extension. I want to open current page URL when click on chrome icon. Now show current page URL in popup. Please help me what can I do in this case.

Please find below code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
        var url = tabs[0].url;
        alert(url);
    });

    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            d = document;
            var f = d.createElement('form');
            f.action = 'http://gtmetrix.com/analyze.html?bm';
            f.method = 'post';
            f.target = '_blank';
            var i = d.createElement('input');
            i.type = 'hidden';
            i.name = 'url';
            i.value = tab.url;
            f.appendChild(i);
            d.body.appendChild(f);
            f.submit();
        });
    }, false);
}, false);
```

```html
<!-- Menifest.json -->
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Test ",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}

<!-- popup.html -- >
<html>
   <head>
     <title>GTmetrix Analyzer</title>
     <script src="popup.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>GTmetrix Analyzer</h1>
     <button id="checkPage">Check this page now!</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me to sort-out this issue?

Thanks

Comment: f.target = '_blank'

Comment: @wOxxOm: Thanks for giving ans.. But its not working. Popup is open.

Comment: Can you show your manifest file.

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to open current page URL when click on chrome icon. Now show current page URL in popup`? Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @wOxxOm: I mean that when i click on chrome extension then current page URL is open to new tab. For ex. Now i am in google.com page and i click on my extension icon then it should open in new tab with Url of goole.com page

Comment: @elegant-user: I have added menifest.json file

Comment: Looking like the problem is in your popup.html file on `<!-- popup.html -- >` line. Just Remove it.

Comment: Or you can replace this`<!-- popup.html -- >` with `<!-- popup.html -->`

Comment: [Chrome Extension's Icon on click](//stackoverflow.com/a/31308640)

Comment: @elegant-user : This is comment part to show you code. Actually there are two different file. Total 3 Files used :  Popup.html, popup.js and menifest.json

Comment: Ok, than there is no problem in your code. Your extension is opening the current tab url in a new tab when you press the browser button.

Comment: @elegant-user : But it is not open in new tab while click on extension icon.. It is open in popup window.

Comment: Not clear on what you want exactly. Do you want to open the current tab url inside you popup.html? Is that correct y/n ?

Comment: @elegant-user :  No. I want to open current tab URL in new tab not in popup.

Comment: The solution is posted as answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170075/discussion-between-tejas-and-elegant-user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in comments. Posting this as an answer.

If you want to grab the url of current tab and open it in a new window. Do  following changes in your popup js file

Replace this code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    alert(url);
});
```

With this code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    chrome.tabs.create({url: url}, function(tab){});
});
```

This will grab the current tab url and open it in a new a new tab.

Also, you can get rid of this code, it is not required anymore.

```
checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            d = document;
            var f = d.createElement('form');
            f.action = 'http://gtmetrix.com/analyze.html?bm';
            f.method = 'post';
            f.target = '_blank';
            var i = d.createElement('input');
            i.type = 'hidden';
            i.name = 'url';
            i.value = tab.url;
            f.appendChild(i);
            d.body.appendChild(f);
            f.submit();
        });
    }, false);
```